# Execute shell commands and print errors to file in node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, mocha.js, sails.js

I have the following `test.js` file for my mocha test

```
var sh = require('execSync');
sh.run("sails generate models test_model &> test_op1.txt");
```

When execute the above code should throw error and that error should store/print to file named test_op1.txt.

I am using Mocha as my test framework.How would I write so that the error instead showing on the terminal should store/print to file test_op1.txt.

Comment: There's something missing in your question, because the way it is written now, the answer to your question is the code you show in your question. What you want to do with Mocha can be done in exactly the same way as without Mocha. If you showed us how you tried to use Mocha, it would probably clarify what you are asking.

Comment: My intention was to store the Output Error to the file and then compare it with known errors for testing userdefined modules.          tempDirLoc=fs.readFileSync('./tempDirLoc.txt','utf8');  assert.equal(tempDirLoc, "Here my defined errors ");                      So that I can test my module